# Mongoose Object ID as a value

Tags: mongoose

In a MongoDB Record, I have an ObjectID. Example:

```js
Record A
{
   _id: ObjectId("62ecef6f8c1fa743580e9828"),
   name: "John"
}

Record B
{
   _id: ObjectId("62e14880ad84f0acd54ae930"),
   title: "How to...",
   user: ObjectId("62ecef6f8c1fa743580e9828"),
}
```

Now as you see in Record B, it has the Object ID of Record A in user.
Is there a way to get the user object directly from Record B since it has the user object ID or I have to find it by the id?

Comment: If the user field ```references record A```, you can get the object by adding ```.populate()``` to the query  https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and there are a couple of ways to do this.

**Populate Method**

Firstly you need to add the reference in your model:

```
const RecordA = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String
    }
  }
)

const RecordB = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
    },
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: RecordA,
      required: true,
    }
  }
)
```

Then you can populate this field by adding `.populate()` method.

```
RecordsA.find().populate('user')
```

Read more here: [Mongoose Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

**$lookup aggregation**

You can use the $lookup aggregation:

```
RecordB.aggregate([
    { $lookup:
        {
           from: "RecordA",
           localField: "user",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "user"
        }
    }
])
```

Read more here: [MongoDB Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)